# @CacheEvict key not working

Tags: spring, caching, spring-boot, guava

When I use CacheEvict with all entries, it works all fine:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "users", allEntries = true)
```

But when I want to use key to remove given cache entry, it just can't find the key and throws NullPointerException. I'm sure I'm passing a non-null value as the parameter.

```
@CacheEvict(value = "users", key = "#username")
void edit(String username, @Param(value = "user") User user);

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:782)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.invalidate(LocalCache.java:5080)
    at org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCache.evict(GuavaCache.java:139)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doEvict(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:98)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.performCacheEvict(CacheAspectSupport.java:480)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.processCacheEvicts(CacheAspectSupport.java:463)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:421)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference the username using `p<#arg>` notation.

E.g. 
`@CacheEvict(value = "users", key = "#p0")`

Should do the trick.

Reference

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html (Table 36.1. Cache SpEL available metadata)

Answer (score 0):

As per 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Under Section:
Available caching SpEL evaluation context

In this case it should be :-

```
@CacheEvict(value = "users", key = "#user.username")
void edit(String username, @Param(value = "user") User user);
```

Comment: I want to use the first argument as the key, so the key name should be "#username"